# Error while testing image source on load in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    {{jsonData[current].profilepic}}
    <div ng-if=IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)>
        <img id="pic" ng-src="{{jsonData[current].profilepic}}"  alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div ng-if=!IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)>
        <div id="pic" class="letter">
            <div class="circle">{{jsonData[current].firstName.charAt(1)+jsonData[current].lastName.charAt(1)}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('task1Controller',['$scope', 'taskFactory', '$state', 'imageTestService', function($scope, taskFactory, $state, imageTestService){

    $scope.taskData = {};
    $scope.current = 0;

    taskFactory.get().then(function(response){
        $scope.jsonData = response.data.data.resultCareGivers;
    });

    $scope.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){        
        return imageTestService.IsValidImageUrl(url); //Error here
    };

    $scope.viewDetails = function(){
        $state.go('view-details', {details: $scope.jsonData[$scope.current]});
    };


    $scope.back = function(){
        $scope.current = ($scope.current !== 0 ? $scope.current - 1 : 0);
    };

    $scope.next = function(){
        $scope.current = ($scope.current !== $scope.jsonData.length-1 ? $scope.current + 1 : $scope.jsonData.length-1);
    };

}]);
```

image test service:

```
app.service('imageTestService', function($q){

    this.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(url != null && url != ""){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onerror = function() { deferred.resolve(false); };
            img.onload =  function() { deferred.resolve(true); };
            img.src = url;
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

});
```

Error stack in console:

[Error link](http://Error%20link)

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>       Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)","newVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"oldVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}}}],[{"msg":"IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)","newVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"oldVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}}}],[{"msg":"IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)","newVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"oldVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}}}],[{"msg":"IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)","newVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"oldVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}}}],[{"msg":"IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)","newVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}},"oldVal":{"$$state":{"status":0}}}]]

Update 2:

```
app.service('imageTestService', function(){

    this.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){
        var result = {};
        if(url != null && url != ""){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onerror = function() { result.val = true };
            img.onload =  function() { result.val = false };
            return result;
        }
    };
});
```

but still the same error in console.

Update 3:

```
app.service('imageTestService', function(){

    this.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){
        var result = {
            val :false
        };
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.onabort = function() { result.val = false };
        this.img.onerror = function() { result.val = false };
        this.img.onload =  function() { result.val = true };
        return result.val;
    };
});
```

In update 3, doesn't matter what I do, always `image.onabort()` is called.

It throws error `fails to load resource` at the function call itself:

```
$scope.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){    //Failed to load resource error    
   return imageTestService.IsValidImageUrl(url); 
};
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are u using $q in your service?

Comment: Vivz is right, you should return boolean values in IsValidImageUrl function.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava how do I return boolean. I think image.onerror or image.onload is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

To get rid of this error we need case where `IsValidImageUrl()` method should return explicit result.

For example you can initialize `result` with default value `false`:

```
 this.IsValidImageUrl = function(url){
    var result = {
      val:false
    };
    if(url != null && url != ""){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onerror = function() { result.val = true };
        img.onload =  function() { result.val = false };
        return result.val;
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Demo with 10 $digest() iterations reached error](http://plnkr.co/edit/ykmspIgPMND5RoEaQ4Ut?p=preview)</kbd>

<kbd>[fixed Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/84OhBnV5btvVCQPshC1a?p=preview)</kbd>

---

#### Long Answer

First off lets understand why we get `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`. Generally its a guard of Angular to get rid of infinite loop of digest cycles that will cause to memory leak and at the end page stuck.

In our case once `IsValidImageUrl` will return different result, Angular will fire new digest cycle and so on - that will lead to above mentioned error.

---

Its not good practice to call methods from `ng-if` | `ng-show/hide` | `ng-style` .... - its a over kill and will effect on your page performance.

I suggest you to call `IsValidImageUrl(jsonData[current].profilepic)` from controller and store it somewhere. for `ng-if` we need boolean value only.

FYI, `Image.onload` and `Image.onError` are callbacks therefore 1st you return empty object `result` and after some delay you update `result` content with `Image.onload` or `Image.onError` callbacks that will fire new digest cycle that will lead to additional call of IsValidImageUrl()`.

`ngIf` directive is a watcher that listens on `result` and after 10 loops will throw `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` exception.

---

Comment: Always `image.onabort()` is called after updating the code.

Comment: Thank you. Updated my code with directive and posted a following question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571610/evaluate-or-call-directive-on-click-in-angular

Comment: @kittu will take a look shortly